# How to get cell properties value in onClick event - react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, dom-events

This is the table:

```html
<table {...getTableProps()}>
            <thead>
              {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                  {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                    <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                      {column.render('Header')}
                    </th>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              ))}
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
              {rows.map(row => {
                prepareRow(row);
                return (
                  <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                    {row.cells.map(cell => {
                      return (
                        <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                      );
                    })}
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Column format:

```
    {
                Header:'STUDENT ID', 
                accessor:'studentid',
        
             },
             {
                Header:'Name', 
                accessor:'name',
        
             },
             {
                Header:'ADDRESS', 
                accessor:'address',
        
             },
             {
               
                Header: "Actions",
                Cell: ({ cell }) => (
                    <span>< button>Edit<button> 
                   /> < button onClick ={ ()=>{handleClick(cell.getCellProps())}} >Delete
                  <button/> </span>
                )
              }
```

Table format:

```
    STUDENTID  NAME  ADDRESS    ACTIONS
      154        xyx    xyx     EDIT&DELETE buttons
      564        abc    abc     EDIT&DELETE buttons
```

On clicking delete button, need to get student Id for API call to delete a particular record of student. I have used functional component for react table.

Handle click function:

```js
const handleClick = (cell) => {
        alert("clicked",cell.studentid);
        console.log(cell);
      }
```

Comment: Not sure how the data is getting there (headerGroups and rows objects). Can you post a sample of the data? 
Anyway, this is how I'd do it, it may help:
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mgxzw5?file=src/App.js)

Comment: What makes the methods `getCellProps()` and `getTableBodyProps`  It seems you're passing the data.